# Go (lang) parsing an email header and keeping order

Tags: email, go, email-headers

I'm using `net/mail` library in Go, everything is great, however I want to pass in an original email and keep the order of the headers. This is important because the mail servers that pass the message on each add their headers in an order. Without order, its hard to know who received what, when and what headers each server added.
The `net/mail` library [stores the headers in a map](https://golang.org/src/net/mail/message.go?s=2594:2625#L97), which by definition has no concept of order. Seems a strange choice as header order is based only on order in the email, but it is the case.
Anyone got any suggestions as to how I can retain order the headers were read?

Thanks

Comment: It stores it in a `map[string][]string` (`textproto.MIMEHeader`). The key is the header name, and the value is a slice for all occurrence of that header, which should be *in order*. I'm not sure why you think they're not ordered? In which case does it fail?

Comment: Because I cant parse the mail headers in, and print them back out and get the original order, but I think I completely missed something then. I parsed a mail, then regenerated the mail from the `net/mail` object and was worried that `Received` and `Received-SPF` would lose order, as the map is not ordered, but you are saying that `Received[0]` matches up with `Received-SPF[0]`. As in an email these will be next to each other when each server adds them, so when recreating the headers from the map I somehow need to put respective header pairs together from the array positions?

Answer (score 1):

The `net/mail` package uses the `net/textproto` package to parse the headers
(see [`ReadMessage()`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/mail/message.go#L53))). Specifically, it uses [`ReadMIMEHeader()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/textproto/#Reader.ReadMIMEHeader) for
the headers, which is documented as:

> The returned map m maps CanonicalMIMEHeaderKey(key) to a sequence of values
>   in the same order encountered in the input.

You can [view the full source](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/textproto/reader.go#L468) if you want, but the basic process is:

```
headers = make(map[string][]string)
for {
    key, value := readNextHeader()
    if key == "" {
        return headers // End of headers
    }

    if headers[key] == nil {
        headers[key] = []string{value}
    } else {
        headers[key] = append(headers[key], value)
    }
}
```

It's true that the original order of the headers as they appeared in the message
is lost, but I'm not aware of any scenario where this truly matters. What
*isn't* lost is the order of the multi-values headers. The slice ensures they're
in the same order as they appeared in the email.

You can verify this with a simple program which loops over the headers and
compares the values ([such as this one in the
Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nG2y_WoCVI)).

---

However, matching `Received` and `Received-SPF` headers is a bit more complex,
as:

1. not every `Received` header may have a corresponding `Received-SPF` header;
2. the `Received-SPF` header may not appear above the `Received` header; this is
   [recommended but *not* mandated by the RFC](http://www.openspf.org/RFC_4408#header-field) (besides, many programs don't
   even follow the RFC, so this wouldn't be a guarantee anyway).

So you'll either need to parse the value of the headers and match them based on
that, or use the `net/textproto` package for more low-level access to the
headers. You can use the source of [`ReadMIMEHeader()`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/textproto/reader.go#L468) as a starting point.